# pool.map() from python multiprocessing library causes JSON error

Tags: python, json, multiprocessing, http-streaming

I'm using the multiprocessing library, which makes it very difficult to debug an error when it occurs. Simple code structure:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import traceback

def myFunction(row):
    try:
       # Create some log strings from row
       string = "[time]: "+row[0]
       # Send log strings to a file
    except Exception as e:
       print "Caught Exception"
       traceback.print_exc()
       print()
       raise e
no_processors = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
with closing(Pool(processes=no_processors)) as pool:
    pool.map(myFunction, list)
```

however, I get this error when running it:

```
Caught exception in worker thread (row = 0):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.py", line 634, in read
  File "filename.multi2.py", line 190, in myFunction
    data = self._response.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 543, in read
    tx.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/cypher.py", line 233, in execute
    return self._post(self._execute or self._begin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/cypher.py", line 208, in _post
    j = rs.json
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.py", line 562, in json
    return self._read_chunked(amt)
    raise TypeError("Content is not JSON")
TypeError: Content is not JSON
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 597, in _read_chunked
()
    raise IncompleteRead(''.join(value))
IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(198 bytes read)
()

    pool.map(myFunction, list)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: Content is not JSON
```

Does anyone know the cause/solution?

Comment: It looks like you are reading json data from an https server, not "Send log strings to a file". The http read is truncated and you get "TypeError: Content is not JSON". Does it work w/o multiprocessing? mp doesn't seem to be envolved here.

Comment: Yes it works without multiprocessing. however there are a LOT of rows - multiprocessing was supposed to 1/8 the time taken to do the tasks. You are correct, it's not just writing to file - it adds a property to nodes in a database (indirectly writing to file).

Comment: UPDATE: I don't get the error if I reduce `processes` to 1, so the error is obviously result of multiple processes doing the same thing.

Comment: @sidewaiise Can you include the *actual* code from `myFunction`? It's really hard to identify the issue without seeing your real code.

Comment: I can't unfortunately, @dano. However I think I have figured out the cause. Will post if it leads to solution.

Comment: the http server may be cancelling connections when it gets too many from one server. Try cpus=2 and scale up from there. If your real code has agressive timeouts, they may need to be relaxed.

Comment: there is a library in use for the http transport called `httpstream` which apparently doesn't bode well with `multiprocessing`. From what I've read nobody has solved the issue yet. might have a look.

Comment: @sidewaiise I'm facing the same issue. Have you come across a solution?

Comment: @intl I never fixed it. You can try forking the library repo and fixing it. I simply ran out of time and had to continue with a serial approach.

Comment: @sidewaiise Could you elaborate on the approach you ended up going with?

Comment: @intl Well instead of using the multiprocessor library, I ended up simply not using it. The benefit of using the multiprocessor library is that you can map a task to multiple processes and reduce the return values much faster than you would in a serial approach. The downfall of using a serial approach is that it will generally just take longer to obtain a result/return value.

Comment: Right. Multiprocessing is essentially to make things faster, which in this case is something I need. Having a traditional iterative approach takes too long.

Comment: @intl Do you have a ticket/post? if you can provide more detail I might be able to offer more assistance.